# Enable FlatList scrolling after its ScrollView parent reaches certain position

Tags: react-native, react-native-gesture-handler

I have this scenario where a FlatList has a ScrollView as parent:

```
<ScrollView>
  <Header />
  <FlatList />
</ScrollView>
```

I want to disable the FlatList scrolling and only enabled it when the ScrollView reaches a certain Y position. All in a single gesture.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

To enable or disable scrolling on FlatList with React Native, we can set the scrollEnabled prop. Is this work for u?

Comment: Well, this doesn't work, because I want both ScrollView and FlatList handled by the same gesture.

If I use the `scrollEnabled` strategy, the user would need to scroll the ScrollView and then scroll the FlatList.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).